# iOS - export multiple pdf

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, pdf, export

In my app, I want to implement the ability to export the multiple pdf files.

For now, I can export an only pdf file using the code below:

```
    // get local path url
    NSURL *url = [self getFileURLWithIndexPath:indexPath];
    if(url) {

        BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[url path]];
        if(!fileExists) {
            NSLog(@"%@", [url path]);
        }

        self.docController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:url];
        [self.docController setDelegate:self];
        BOOL canOpenFile = [self.docController presentOpenInMenuFromRect:self.view.frame inView:self.view animated:YES];
        if(!canOpenFile) {
            // No reader PDF
        }
    }
```

The `url` is the local URL path.
This method will popup where I can choose iBooks to export.
But I have no idea how to export multiple files, can anyone help me...?
Thank!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use UIActivityViewController to export multiple files and can open in UIDocumentationInteractionController, it provides in-app support for managing user interactions with files in the local system.

```
NSArray *dataItems = @[pdf1, pdf2, pdf3];
UIActivityViewController *activityViewController =
[[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:dataItems
                                  applicationActivities:nil];
[self presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:^{

}];
```

Comment: Thank you @abdullahselek, it works for sharing with email and Airdrop! But can you also specify how to use UIDocumentationInteractionController to save these PDF in iBooks after UIActivityViewController shown? I only see one email option. Thanks

Comment: Try adding excluded types like `// try adding excluded types activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard];` and for more info activity types [link](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiactivitytype)

Comment: Thanks again @ abdullahselek. Adding excluded types does not really help me. After researching on internet, I figured out that we cannot open multiple documents at the same time. But I still chose your answer as the best solution, It really helped me :)